# get multidimension array key value to single array php

Tags: php

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 62,
            "user_id": "34",
            "updated_at": "2017-10-15 08:24:32",
            "request": {
                "data": "yes",
                "watch": "Pending"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "user_id": "34",
            "updated_at": "2017-10-15 08:24:32",
            "request": {
                "data": "yes",
                "watch": "Yes"
            }
        },   ]
}
```

How can i get the watch value to under the updated_at
As Expected

```
"list": [
        {
 "id": 62,
 "user_id": "34",
 "updated_at": "2017-10-15 08:24:32",
 "watch": "Pending"
}..
```

I tried using array_column but doesn't work for me.

```
function array_column($array, $column){
            $ret = array();
            foreach($array as $row){
                $ret[] = $row[$column];
                return $ret;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding, you have two events with the same time stamp?  How do you know which one is most recent?

Comment: Well, first thing is that the `return $ret` should be outside of the foreach. But other than that I don't quite get the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat like

```
function updateArray(&$array){
    foreach($array['list']  as $key => $item){
        $array['list'][$key]['watch'] = $item['request']['watch'];
        unset($array['list'][$key]['request']);
    }
}
updateArray($array);
print_r($array);
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/453f4e968a743abcc90e0a8cb9d22f08247409ca)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know that you need to decode the JSON first:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then access the array under the `list` element:

```
$result = array_column($array['list'], 'updated_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a good challenge.here you are

```
 <pre>
<?php
$array=array("list"=>array(array("id"=>"62","user_id"=>"32","updated_at"=>2017,"request"=>array("data"=>"yes","watch"=>"panddin")),
                          array("id"=>"60","user_id"=>"30","updated_at"=>2016,"request"=>array("data"=>"no","watch"=>"pan"))));
//print_r($array);

            foreach($array as $row){
                foreach ($row as $key => $value){
                       if((is_array($value))){
                        foreach ($value as  $key1 => $k){
                              if((is_array($k))){
                              foreach ($k as $key2 => $value2) {
                                     echo $key2."=>". $value2."<br>";
                              }

                              }else echo  $key1."=>".$k."<br>";    

                              }

                       }else echo $key."=>".$value. "<br>"; 
                  }


            }
?>
 </pre>
```